# Is it Spam when a questioner requests replies be posted on a different site?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, spam, cross-posting

Regarding [How can I convert my Excel VBA Macros to EXE File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002366), the user posted this in comments:

> I have posted this same thread on the below forum. Please check there and then reply over there. Thanks. <link to cross-posted question on another site>

I flagged this for moderation attention with a note about the comment but then I started thinking that this was a form of second-hand spam.

What would be the correct form of action to take? I couldn't think of a valid vote-to-close reason.

Comment: I don't think it's spam unless they're promoting something of their own: their own blog, business, or something they're affiliated with. As it is, they've gotten into trouble on the *other* site because cross posting is against their rules. So I don't think this counts as self-promotion.

Comment: Flag the comment as NLN, and move on, IMO.

Comment: What if it's a github ticket? I mean one can open a ticket and then use it as reference for an SO question. Does it qualify as spam for you?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I flagged this for moderation attention with a note about the comment
>   but then I started thinking that this was a form of second-hand spam.

That depends. In theory it could be a clever way to second hand spam for a different forum site, but that's unlikely. More likely then that it's just someone wanting to cross post. It is noise though.

> What would be the correct form of action to take? I couldn't think of
>   a valid vote-to-close reason.

I'd flag the comment as no longer needed and edit any such references out of the question.

Comment: indeed, it sounds like the person want's the answerer to get the correct credit there as well on the face of it.

Comment: If it worked (the answer was posted to the target forum and no answers were posted to the question here) then it would drive clicks to the forum up and Google would rank it higher. It's extremely unlikely that such a scheme would work though because of IIP.